# Insert rows in UITableView from code

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

This seems ridiculous but I can't seem to sort it out. I need to insert a row in a table view in response to a push notification. The implementation should be as simple as

```
- (void)didSaveMessage:(Message*)message atIndex:(int)index
{
//check to make sure I have an array to populate the table from...
    if (self.messageManager.messages != nil)
    {   
        self.indexRow = index;
        NSLog(@"refresh table view from code");
        //remove a label that says "You have no messages"...
        [[messageTable tableFooterView] removeFromSuperview];

        [messageTable beginUpdates];
        [messageTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]] 
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [messageTable endUpdates];

        [self scrollToNewestMessage];

    }
}
```

This method is called when I receive a remote notification and it does fire. The log statement prints. However, the UITableView does not update. What is particularly strange to me is that if I put the same code in an IBAction and link it to a refresh button in storyboard, it works. Is there something special that I have to do to update a UITableView programmatically?

Comment: Make sure that your datasource has already been updated with the data for this new row before this call to update is invoked. I'm assuming you're aware that animating a row into the table and adding a row to your datasource are discrete actions.

Comment: Yes, thanks. If I log the count of the array that I am using to populate the table before making the insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation call, I get the expected updated count. That part seems to be fine. Besides, if my data source had not yet been updated when I attempted to insert a new row, I would get an NSException and crash, would I not?

Comment: Good point, that would throw an `NSInternalInconsistencyException`. If you're further down in the table than the row being added, does it scroll to the correct row? Also, I'm not sure if removing the tableFooterView from its superview is a great idea since that's part of `UITableView`'s view hierarchy. I would probably be setting that to `nil` instead. It seems odd that this works when fired by a button...

Comment: Thanks, I changed the tableFooterView thing. The row that I am adding is always at the last index, cause I'm getting the indexPath by array.count - 1. And yeah, I agree. It makes no sense to me at all that I should be able to get it to work through an -(IBAction) but not via a direct call to a -(void) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. I was calling the method to update the UI from didReceiveRemoteNotification: in the AppDelegate but to a different instance of my view controller. So I added a viewController property onto the app delegate, set the value for that in my view controller's view did load, and now it's all working.

Answer (score 1):

Try to send the table the `reloadData` message. This should force the table view to update.

Comment: No dice. Thank you for your response. I tried reloadData both instead of and in addition to insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation:. The result is the same, no update to the table. If I navigate away from the view and come back, the reloadData call in viewWillAppear loads all the messages for the table correctly and, as I mentioned, it works in response to a UIEvent. But not from code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty trivial, but is it possible that the Message* that you are passing into the didSaveMessage is nil?  It would explain why the NSLog statement works, and I would assume that you had to create the message manually when testing from an IBAction.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I log the message to console, it exists as expected. And when testing from an IBAction I was still sending the message via push notifications, just loading it with a refresh button instead of in response to didReceiveRemoteNotification: